# How do I get Windows 8.1 to display image thumbnails when using the modern explorer?

Tags: windows-8, windows-explorer, images

This is a most frustrating problem with image thumbnails in Windows 8.1; I'm not sure when exactly my computer started doing this.  The problem only affects browsing pictures in the modern explorer (i.e. the traditional Windows explorer behaves as expected).

First if I go to the "Photos" modern app and browse a folder in my pictures library, I see image thumbnails... great! This works as expected.

However if I use another modern app (an app launched from the Start Screen) which requires me to browse and select a photo, if I navigate to the same location that I was in with the Photos app, I see the default image icons instead of thumbnails of my images. For instance this is what I see if go to Change Account Picture from the Start Screen.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but this is how Windows 8.1 works. I'd better recommend you to wait for Windows 10(will launch in fall 2015) which incorporates capability to group modern apps functionality as like Desktop so you could see pictures thumbnail even if browsing it using Apps.